# cant display uploaded image django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Why can't I display my uploaded images correctly using the following settings. 
The url is showing correctly (I think) when viewing the page source. The image is just the broken image thumbnail image. The url in the source is shown as `/media/uploads/group_images/my_image_name`

If relevant, the image was uploaded from admin, but I also want to be able to upload elsewhere (ie - upload form in the rendered template)

in settings.py

```
....
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIAFILES_DIRS = []
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

in models.py

```
class BlogGroup(models.Model):

    title = BleachField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/group_images", default="uploads/group_images/none/none.jpg")
    created = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title
```

in forms.py

```
class BlogGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(BlogGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["title"].requried = True
        self.fields["image"].required = True
        self.fields["title"].widget = forms.TextInput()

    class Meta:
        model = BlogGroup
        fields = ["title", "image"]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
 (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  .....,
 (r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
 (r"", "main"),
 ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

view

```
def main(request):

    groups = BlogGroup.objects.all().order_by("created")
    context = {'groups':groups, 'user':request.user}
    return render(request, "list.html", context)
```

template

```
{% for group in groups %}
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
        {{ group.title }}
    </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
        <img src = "{{ group.image.url }}" alt = ""/>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Try to go on http://.../media/. Is there any errors?

Comment: Oh, I've understand, wait a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your url dispatcher.
When django proceeding url to dispatcher, it goes from top to bottom throw your urls, one by one, and stops if there is regexp match.

Your url `""` in `(r"", "main"),` matches ALL strings.
You need to replace it to `(r"^$", "main"),` to match just empty strings.

More info:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/
- https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html

Comment: Wow, silly mistake on my part. Thank you for pointing that out this was driving me insane!

Answer (score 0):

change you url.py like this:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
 (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  .....,
 (r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
 (r"", "main"),
 ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: OOOh yes in you template add this <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ group.image }}"/>

Comment: maybe this object have not image ! look my friend have you firebug ? use it what do you see  on this img tag ? what appear ?